# How to clear Word undo stack using Javascript API for Word

Tags: javascript, ms-word, ms-office, office-js, undo

I am creating a Word add-in using Javascript API for Word, wherein the user searches for a phrase and the phrase gets highlighted in the document. There is also a reset button, which restores the document to the pre-search state. Here, two events are getting added to the undo stack.

[some state A]
1. phrase highlighting
2. undo phrase highlighting
[same state A]

Is there a way I can achieve state A without adding two events in the undo stack? Like, if the user presses Ctrl+Z, they do not go through step 2 and step 1.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid not. You cannot manipulate the undo stack from an add-in today.

There is however a UserVoice request for this functionality that could use your votes: [Remove Changes Made by the Javascript API for Office from the Undo Stack](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/6962932-remove-changes-made-by-the-javascript-api-for-offi)

Comment: Is there a way, at least, to disable the undo functionality completely while the add-in is enabled and in use?

Comment: I'm afraid not. The add-in operates within it's own sandbox. The only interaction between host application (i.e. Word) and your add-in is over the secure channel established by Office.js. Without an specific API that supports the action you want (i.e. the undo stack), there is no way to control it from an add-in.

Comment: Marc, the UserVoice entry you link to is for Excel. Would voting for that also imply Undo for Word? Or should I start a new entry'